# Error "No converter for [class [B] with preset Content-Type 'null'" for SpringBoot API that returns Excel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I'm implementing an API that create an Excel file with Apache POI and Java 1.8 and returns it as a response.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadExcel(@RequestParam String param) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = service.createExcel(param);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(stream);
    workbook.close();
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .body(stream.toByteArray());
}
```

When I try to call the API with Postman I get this error:

```
"title": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500,
"detail": "No converter for [class [B] with preset Content-Type 'null'"
```

If I save the file to my machine I can see that the file is being generated correctly. So the problem really is in the answer. If I remove the mime-type the API responds with status 200, but with messy content that doesn't open in excel.

Comment: Probably your postman is sending the wrong `Accept` headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing the error. Someone set up HttpMessageConverters in the API and make it returns Content-Type: "application/problem+json".